# Scale animation in Android degrades image quality

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

> In Android 5.0 (API Level 21) and above, you can define vector
>   drawables, **which scale without losing definition.**

I use Vector Assets in Android Studio (API 28). Example: [ic_mybutton.xml](https://ufile.io/xnhqtbjt).
Vector drawables are displayed on Views in original quality: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFg5T.png), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6l2c.jpg), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8X0Y.jpg).

```
ImageButton button = new ImageButton(context);
button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mybutton);
```

Using this animation on Buttons and ImageButtons (or other Views):

```
Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation(
        1.0f, 0.9f,
        1.0f, 0.9f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setDuration(1000);
button.startAnimation(animation);
```

produces terrible image distortion: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHIx8.png), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cff1.jpg), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUs9M.jpg).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved using the animator.

**All other known libraries, such as [Boom](https://github.com/astrit-veliu/Boom), [RxAnimation](https://github.com/lopspower/RxAnimation) and the like, degrade image quality when scaling.**

*anim_scale.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.9"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.9"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

*animated_vector.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_mybutton">
    <target
        android:animation="@animator/anim_scale"
        android:name="anim_scale" />
</animated-vector>
```

Put your paths in `<group>` tag and set the pivot.

*ic_mybutton.xml:*

```
<group
  android:name="anim_scale"
  android:pivotX="177.5"
  android:pivotY="37.5">
  ...
</group>
```

Thus (with slight changes), you can make an animation of a button click without losing vector image quality:

```
ImageButton button = findViewById(R.id.button_apply);
button.setImageResource(R.drawable.animated_vector);
button.setOnClickListener(v -> ((Animatable) button.getDrawable()).start());
```

P.S.
Following method does not work (losing quality):

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "scale", 0.9f);
animator.setDuration(200);
animator.start();
```

And StateListAnimator class also degrades image quality.